# Как одним SQL запросом выбрать данные из двух таблиц БД?

Tags: mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на фото 3 таблицы, в первой "Предмет", во второй "Преподаватель" и таблица связи между ними (в ней id предмета и преподавателя).

У меня есть название предмета и я по этому названию должен вывести его преподавателя. Я могу это сделать, но будет 2 sql  запроса:

```
"SELECT * FROM lesson_teacher
INNER JOIN lesson
ON lesson.id = lesson_teacher.kod_lesson WHERE lesson.name = 'нужный предмет'"
```

Из этого запроса я узнаю только id нужного преподавателя.

```
"SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE id = "найденный ID" "
```

А вопрос в том, можно ли это сделать одним запросом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t.* 
  FROM lesson l
  INNER JOIN lesson_teacher lt
      ON lt.kod_lesson = l.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN teacher t
      ON lt.kod_teacher = t.id
  WHERE l.name LIKE '%lesson_name%'
  GROUP BY t.id
```

`LIKE '%lesson_name%'` выберет похожиe предметы.Если вам нужно по точным названиям то удалить знак процента.

Comment: в данном случае  LIKE '%lesson_name%' может привести к ложным результатам

Comment: @Alex В вопросе не уточняются детали

Comment: @0xdb Вы о чем,почему должен ругаться ? Сторайтесь приводить больше информации,чтоб нe приходилось догадываться.

Comment: @0xdb В оригинале стояло `phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t.* FROM lesson_teacher lt
INNER JOIN lesson ls ON ls.id = lt.kod_lesson 
INNER JOIN teacher t ON t.id = lt.kod_teacher 
WHERE ls.name = 'нужный предмет'
```